# Why do routes in Laravel's HTTP kernel use fully qualified class names AND ::class?

Tags: php, laravel, class

There is a lot of this going on in \App\http\Kernel.php. If absolute class names are explicitly provided, why bother with PHP's ::class feature (to return the fully qualified class names)?

Example:

`protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,`

Comment: What else would you pass otherwise?

Comment: @ChinLeung Why use both? For example, `\App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode` or `CheckForMaintenanceMode::class`

Comment: The fully qualified name is already provided, so adding `::class` is redundant?

Comment: `::class` turns it into a string. It's got nothing to do with redundance.

Comment: So does wrapping it in quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just a best practice. You could use anything that leads to fully-qualified class name as a string like all of those are valid:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
```

and

```
use App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode;
//...
protected $middleware = [
    CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
```

and

```
protected $middleware = [
    '\App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
```

BUT. With the last one as we are using a string, it's harder to refactor using IDE built-in refactoring tools. Suppose you want to rename `CheckForMaintenanceMode` to `MaintenanceMode`, IDEs will properly rename in first 2 cases, but not the later one (it's hard to determine weather a string is a class-reference or... just a string)

So, the answer is: it's a best practice to reference fully qualified class names using `::class`

Comment: I think I get it. We can't just say `CheckForMaintenanceMode::class` without adding a `use` statement? If I remember correctly, because PHP would only check the current namespace rather than the global one.

Comment: @MichaelNovello yep, whenever you are referencing something outside current namespace you either required to use fully-qualified class name, or "import" the class first using `use`.